Quadratic with integer roots
This question is from the 1991 Russian Mathematics Olympiad Grade 10 Final round.
I have searched as best I can on this site and AoPS for a solution to compare to my own but with no luck.
The question
Find all natural numbers $p,q$ for which $x^2-pqx+p+q=0$ has integral roots.
My attempt at a solution
Let the roots be $a,b$ then $a+b=p\times q$ and $a\times b=p+q$
Assuming zero is not a natural number, the only obvious solution is $p=q=2$ which makes the original quadratic $x^2-4x+4=0$.
I tried writing $b=pq-a$ which leads to $a^2-apq+p+q=0$ which doesn't seem to be much help, so I am wondering if the only solution is $p=2,q=2$.
Edit
Thanks to the comments of PrincessEev and Martin R, it seems like the only solutions are $(2,2), (2,3)$ and $(5,1)$.

Just playing in Desmos right now (link) but $p=2$ and $q=3$ work. Also: $(p,q)=(5,1)$

Thanks. I feel there is something really simple I have missed.

On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1677456p10687339, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1392587p7771350

Yep - that is the same problem alright. Thanks.

It ssems to me that $pq < p + q +1$ (from the second link) is the crucial observation.

Thanks - I'm still working through these threads. You are most welcome to post an answer if you are convinced these are the only three solutions (I'm 99% convinced, just trying to think through it all).

0 isn't a natural number....you don't have to assume that fact

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad - I agree but a lot of people I work with believe differently so it is a habit I have developed to be clear what I mean by Natural number. I should have known better on a site like this though.

The following is taken from Equation and integers on AoPS.
Let $p, q$ be positive integers such that  $f(x) = x^2 - pq x + (p+q)$ has integral roots. Then $f(0) = p + q > 0$, so that necessarily $f(1) \ge 0$, i.e.
$$
 pq \le p + q + 1 \, .
$$
If $q \ge 2$ then the last inequality implies $p \le 3$, and vice versa.
If $q=1$ and $f(x) = x^2 - px + (p+1)$ has integral roots $(a, b)$ then $a+b = p$ and $ab = p+1$, so that
$$
 (a-1)(b-1) = (p+1)- p + 1 = 2
$$
and $(a-1, b-1)$ must be one of $(1, 2), (2, 1), (-1, -2), (-2, -1)$. The last two pairs can be excluded because $ab \ne 0$, therefore $p = a+b = 5$.
Therefore the only possible solutions are $(p, q) = (2,2), (2, 3),(3, 2), (1, 5), (5, 1)$. It remains to verify that $f(x) = 0$ has integral solutions in all these cases, which is not difficult.

Beautifully summarised. Thanks. I found the second link took a few leaps of logic, but your answer here makes very good sense.

My initial answer overlooked an analytical shortcut that may be used to moderately streamline the demonstration.  I have added an Addendum, at the end of my answer, to provide the shortcut.

$$x^2 -pqx +(p+q) = 0 \implies $$
$$x = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~pq \pm \sqrt{ ~p^2q^2 - 4(p + q) ~} ~\right]. \tag1 $$
On confronting (1) above, my first question is: 
what effect does the $~\dfrac{1}{2}~$ factor place on the odd/even parity of $~p~$ and $~q~?$
Temporarily assuming that $~p^2q^2 - 4(p+q)~$ is a perfect square, you have that the square of a number is even if and only if the original number  is even.  Then, since $~4~$ is an even number, the expression under the radical will be even if and only if $~p^2q^2~$ is even.
Then, $~p^2q^2~$ will be even if and only if $~pq~$ is even.
Therefore, the presence of the $~\dfrac{1}{2}~$ factor may be ignored.

Therefore, the entire problem reduces to identifying all $~(p,q)~$ such that
$$S = \left[ ~p^2q^2 - 4(p + q) ~\right] \tag2 $$
is a perfect square.
Since
$$(pq)^2 - (pq - 1)^2 = 2pq - 1,$$
a natural question to ask is 
under what circumstances is
$$2pq - 1 > 4(p + q) ~? \tag3 $$
Suppose that $~p \geq 5, ~q \geq 5.~$
Then $~pq > 4p ~$ and $~pq > 4q.~$
Therefore, without loss of generality, $~p \in \{1,2,3,4\}.~$
Further, with respect to the original problem, it is understood that if $~(p=n_1,q=n_2)~$ is a solution, then so is $~(p = n_2,q = n_1).$

$p = 1 \implies S = q^2 - 4q - 4 = (q - 2)^2 - 8.$ 
Then $~(q - 2)^2 - n^2 = 8 \implies $ 
$[ ~(q - 2) -  ~n ~] \times [ ~(q - 2) + ~n ~] = 8.$ 
Since the two factors have the same parity, you must have that
$[ ~(q-2) - n ~] = 2, [ ~(q - 2) + n ~] = 4.$ 
Therefore, $~n = 1,~$ and $~q = 5.~$
Therefore, $~(p,q) = (1,5)~$ is a solution.

$p = 2 \implies S = 4q^2 - 4q - 8 = (2q - 1)^2 - 9.$ 
Then $~(2q - 1)^2 - n^2 = 9 \implies $ 
$[ ~(2q - 1) -  ~n ~] \times [ ~(2q - 1) + ~n ~] = 9.$ 
Since $~9~$ is a perfect square, you can have 
$n = 0 \implies q = 2 \implies (p,q) = (2,2)~$ is a solution. 
Alternatively, you have that $~(2q - 1) - n = 1, ~(2q - 1) + n = 9 \implies $ 
$n = 4, q = 3 \implies (p,q) = (2,3)~$ is a solution.

$p = 3 ~: ~$ the already discovered solution of $~(p,q) = (3,2)~$  will be ignored.
Here, I will focus on the inequality in (3) above. 
Under what circumstances is $~6q - 1 > 4q + 12.$ 
This will be true if $~q \geq 7.~$ 
So, with $~p = 3,~$ the only candidate values to check are 
$~q \in \{1,3,4,5,6\}.$ 
Further, $~p = 3 \implies S = 9q^2 - 4q - 12.$ 
By inspection, there is no other solution when $~p = 3.~$

$p = 4 ~: ~$ 
Here, I will focus on the inequality in (3) above. 
Under what circumstances is $~8q - 1 > 4q + 16.$ 
This will be true if $~q \geq 5.~$ 
So, with $~p = 4,~$ the only candidate values to check are 
$~q \in \{1,2,3,4\}.$ 
Further, $~p = 4 \implies S = 16q^2 - 4q - 16.$ 
By inspection, there is no solution when $~p = 4.~$


So, the only solutions are $~(1,5), ~(2,2)~$ and $~(2,3).$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
My initial analysis overlooked that since $~4~$ is an even number, that $~(pq)^2~$ and S [from (2) above] must have the same parity.  It is therefore impossible for $~S~$ to equal $~(pq - 1)^2.$
Therefore, since
$$(pq)^2 - (pq-2)^2 = 4pq - 4,$$
it becomes relevant to ask: 
under what circumstances is
$$4pq - 4 > 4(p+q) \iff pq > (p + q) + 1. \tag4 $$
Suppose that $~p \geq 3,~$ and $~q \geq 3.~$
Then
$$(p-2) \times (q-2) > 0 \iff pq > 2(p+q) - 4 \iff $$
$$pq > [ ~(p+q) + 1 ~] + [ ~(p+q) - 5 ~].$$
So, when $~p \geq 3,~$ and $~q \geq 3,$ 
since this implies that $[ ~(p+q) - 5 ~] > 0,$ 
it also implies that the inequality in (4) above must hold.
Therefore, you can assume, without loss of generality, that $~p \leq 2.~$
Therefore, in the first part of my answer, the manual considerations of $~p=3~$ and $~p=4~$ are unnecessary.

Very clever to look at the odd/even nature of natural numbers. Great answer.
